# comparison of Integer with String failed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

In my money controller, I have defined this method to get the sorted list by money but I am getting an error `comparison of Integer with String failed`. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.
Below is the sample `JSON` record.

```
{
  "Name":"Tony",
  "xyz":0,
  "money":"7"
}


  def sort_money
    require 'json'
    require 'csv'
    f = File.open("app/assets/javascripts/sample.json")
    @mylist = JSON.parse(f.read).sort_by{ |v| v["money"] }
  end
```

Comment: Your json file contains both integers and strings for the parameter `money`. Can you please check the json file once.

Comment: @RahulSharma yes it is correct, it contains integers and string both

Comment: Use `to_i` to convert string to integers. `@mylist = JSON.parse(f.read).sort_by{ |v| v["money"].to_i }`

Comment: @RahulSharma it worked thankx

Comment: @RahulSharma could you please add an answer to not leave the question unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json file contains both integers and strings for the parameter money. Use `to_i` to convert string to integers. Like this:

```
@mylist = JSON.parse(f.read).sort_by{ |v| v["money"].to_i }
```